# Simple_form : Adapt inputs to width of parent div

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

In my Rails app, I'm using simple_form and trying to customize it. My problem is that the `input` and `textarea` of the `simple_form_for` has a preset `width`, and I want them to adapt to the size of the parent `div` (defined with Bootstrap columns). In the preset of `simple_form`, the `width` is set at `100%`(in a class called `.form-control`. I can't put a larger percentage, of it won't be responsive and adapt to my boostrap columns. 
Do you have any idea how can I do? 
Here is my html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <h2>
        <%= f.input :title, placeholder: 'Title of the project', label: false, input_html: {class: "title"} %>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <h4>
        <%= f.input :description, as: :text, placeholder: 'Description about this project', label: false %>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can add `wrapper: false` to your input or do `f.input_field` instead.. see if that helps.

Comment: thanks vlad `wrapper: false` was the solution :)